# printf for float behaves differently if position changed

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I've below piece of code :

```
float i=85.00;
printf("%f %p",i,i);
```

which prints o/p:

```
85.00000 (nil)
```

But when I change the order like below:

```
    float i=85.00;
    printf("%p %f",i,i);
```

the o/p is :

```
(nil) 0.00000
```

While I expect that similar o/p should be printed as earlier, in mentioned order.
What is the behaviour going on can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're doing is **undefined behavior**.  The `%p` format specifier promises that you're passing in a pointer (specifically a `void*` pointer), and you're passing in a `double` instead (`float` values get promoted to `double` when passed to variadic functions such as `printf`).  So as soon as you fail to satisfy the requirements, the compiler and implementation are free to do whatever they want, and printing out 0 instead of 85 in the second case is perfectly legal.

What's likely happening is that the compiler is using a calling convention which places floating-point values in separate registers (e.g. the x87 floating-point stack, or the SSE2 SIMD registers) instead of on the stack, whereas integer values like pointers get passed on the stack.  So when the implementation sees a `%p` format specifier, it tries to read the argument off of the stack, when in fact the argument is actually elsewhere.

As others have mentioned, you should really be compiling with the `-Wall` option (assuming GCC or a GCC-compatible compiler).  It will help you catch these kinds of errors.

Comment: Thanks.. I knew that I'm deliberately using %p which expects pointer.. but I was just playing around with printf , so came across this :) Didn't know though that it is undefined.

        "float values get promoted to double when passed to variadic functions such as printf" - do you have any reference where I can get to know more about this, this sounds interesting

Comment: @DiwakarSharma Here is a link to the C99 standard, a good compromise between conciseness and precision (the C standards only get longer with time). http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf

Comment: Even if all the values are passed on the stack, the behavior could be due to a pointer taking 4 bytes and a double 8. The first version would pick up all 8 bytes one of the copies of `i`. The second version would use, for the %f, the last half of the first copy and the second half of the second double.

Answer (score 8):

`printf()` expects a pointer for the format specifier `%p` whereas you are passing the *value* of a float. This is undefined behaviour.

If you want to print the address, then pass the address:

```
printf("%f %p",i, &i);
```

If you turn on the **warnings**, you'll see the problem:

> warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 3
>   has type ‘double’ [-Wformat]

Answer (score 3):

You are probably hitting some [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior); printing a float as a pointer has absolutely no sense.

And GCC 4.8 invoked as `gcc -Wall` rightly warns you:

```
dwakar.c:5:3: warning: format '%p' expects argument of type 'void *', 
              but argument 3 has type 'double' [-Wformat=]
   printf("%f %p",i,i);
   ^
```

So please use `gcc -Wall` to compile your code and correct it till no warnings are given.

Notice that at the ABI level floating point and pointers arguments are passed thru different registers. So the implementation probably prints as pointer the (uninitialized, or old) content of whatever register is involved.